# Drawing bounding box at certain positions in an image using Octave

Tags: image-processing, octave, bounding-box

I have a grayscale image of size 128 by 256. I ran sliding window algorithm on this image using 8 by 16 sliding window with a stride of 16 in horizontal direction and 8 in the vertical direction. So, the original grayscale image can be seen as a grid of 8 by 16 small windows.
I want to draw an 8 by 16 bounding box around each of these small windows(256 in this case). I wrote following code:

```
w=16;h=8;
%Get row and column number for each small window of size 8 by 16.
[C,R]=ind2sub([size(grayImg,1)/8, size(grayImg,2)/16],(1:256));
for idx = 1:256
   if (R(idx)>1)
       r=(R(idx)-1)*h;
   else
       r=R(idx);
   endif

   if (C(idx)>1)
       c=(C(idx)-1)*w;
   else
       c=C(idx);
   endif

   if (IDX(idx)==1)
       rectangle('Position', [r, c, w, h],  'EdgeColor','r', 'LineWidth', 2)
   elseif (IDX(idx)==2)
       rectangle('Position', [r, c, w, h],  'EdgeColor','g', 'LineWidth', 2)
   endif
endfor
```

However, I'm not able to achieve the desired result. The result obtained by running this code is available at https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx0v6.jpg
Please help me modify the code to achieve the desired result.

Comment: You need to reverse `r` and `c`: `rectangle('Position', [c, r, w, h], ...`

Comment: @beaker Thank You!! It worked. I also understood the mistake I did.